# Choosing what to log in mysql binary logs

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm running the mysql-server-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.

I'm getting some strange behaviours in the database, and I'd like to store some actions.

Reading the Mysql Reference Manual, I set the binary-logs and started logging all what happened in the database.

But the log files are too big, and I'd like to know if there is a way to configure the binary log to store just some actions (like ALTER TABLE, or DELETE, or CREATE INDEX) instead logging all actions.

If yes, how can I do it.

Rgds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the binary logs is to record state changes on the server. If it changes state, it gets recorded.

Comment: So, in your opinion, the solution should be a filter running in background to read from binary log created files and extract the information that I want?

Comment: If you can figure out how to parse the MySQL binary logs, that might be one way to do it. I'm not sure how open that specification is.